# osmdroid ItemizedOverlay error: The method boundCenterBottom(Drawable) is undefined for the type

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay, osmdroid

I'm struggling for some hours now with this problem:

I'm trying to get my itemizedoverlay to work, but I keep getting this error:

```
The method boundCenterBottom(Drawable) is undefined for the type
```

my class:

```
    public MyDynamicItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

        items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        populate();

    }

    public void addNewItem(GeoPoint location, String markerText,
            String snippet) {
        items.add(new OverlayItem(snippet, markerText, location));
        populate();
    }

    public void removeItem(int index) {
        items.remove(index);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int index) {
        return items.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSnapToItem(int arg0, int arg1, Point arg2,
            IMapView arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

I'm using osmdroid-android-3.0.8 and 3.0.7 (tried both).
ItemizedOverlay in deed seems not to have such constructor, but ALL of samples I was able to google followed the same pattern...

Comment: workaround: replace the line with boundCenterBottom with

//   super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
   super(defaultMarker, new ResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext()));

- simply not use the missing method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, it seem's that the answer to my question is that this method is not implemented in osmdroid and:

```
item.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

should be used insteed

Comment: Dear Szymon. I have quite similar code to yours after trying to make the HelloGoogleMaps example work with OSMdroid. I got the same error-message as you and replaced the line
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
with what you suggested but it raises the error "item cannot be resolved" and "Implicit super constructor ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor" How exactly is the setMarkerHotspot method to be used here?

Comment: @birgit: I think you have to replace `yourPOIOverlayItem.setMarker(boundCenterBottom(yourMarker));` with `yourPOIOverlayItem.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.BOTTOM_CENTER);
yourPOIOverlayItem.setMarker(yourMarker);`