# Android HelloGoogleMaps to OSMdroid (Open Street Maps)

Tags: android, openstreetmap, itemizedoverlay, osmdroid

I am trying to reproduce a working HelloGoogleMaps app in Open Street Maps - but I have trouble including the itemized overlay in OSMdroid.

I have looked at several resources but I cannot figure out how to fix the error on OsmItemizedOverlay - I guess I am constructing OsmItemizedOverlay wrongly or have a mixup with OsmItemizedOverlay and ItemizedOverlay? But everything I tried to change just raised more errors...
"Implicit super constructor ItemizedOverlay() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor"
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setMarker(Drawable) from the type OverlayItem" - I hope someone can help me getting the class definition straight?

Thanks so much!

```
package com.example.osmdroiddemomap;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import org.osmdroid.api.IMapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.*;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.*;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem.HotspotPlace;

public class OsmItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    Context mContext;


    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

        //ERRORS are raised by the following 3 lines:
    public OsmItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
            OverlayItem.setMarker(defaultMarker);
            OverlayItem.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.CENTER);

          mContext = context; 
            }

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
  return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
  return mOverlays.size();
}


  protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSnapToItem(int arg0, int arg1, Point arg2, IMapView arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your constructor like this

```
public OsmItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
    }
```

Comment: This is the constructor as I had it working in the Google Maps Example but the method boundCenterBottom is not defined in OSMdroid... that's why I followed threads like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667208/

Answer (score 0):

I've never used osmdroid, but looking at documentation in [here](http://android.martinpearman.co.uk/b4a/osmdroid/documentation/native_android_library/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/OverlayItem.html), it shows `setMarkerHotspot()` as method of `OverlayItem`, and the documentation in [enter link description here](http://android.martinpearman.co.uk/b4a/osmdroid/documentation/native_android_library/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ItemizedOverlay.html) says that default marker is always botton center aligned.

So to solve it, you will need to assign a marker to each overlay item added, and set the `setMarkerHotspot()` to center.

Something like this should solve the issue:

```
Context mContext; 
Drawable mDefaultMarker;

public OsmItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) { 
      mContext = context;  
      mDefaultMarker = defaultMarker;  
} 

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    overlay.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.CENTER);
    mOverlays.add(overlay);   
    populate();   
}
```

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your addItem function to:

```
public void addItem(OverlayItem item) {
    item.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.CENTER);
    mOverlay.addItem(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use following constructor:

  public OsmItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
            super(defaultMarker,context);
            mContext = context;
        }

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}
```